# weird characters in Pandas dataframe - how to standardize to UTF-8?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

I'm using Python + Camelot (OCR library) to read a PDF, clean up, and write to Excel or csv. There are some non-standard dashes that print out a weird character.

Using Camelot means I'm not calling "read_csv". It's coming from the PDF. A value that is supposed to be "1-4" prints out as 1â€“4.

I fixed this using a regular expression but a colleague mentioned I should standardize to UTF-8. I tried to do that for the header like this:

```
header = df.iloc[0, 1:].str.encode('utf-8')
```

but then that value becomes b'1\xe2\x80\x934'.

Any advice? The goal is to simply use standard text.

Comment: When you say that " '1-4' prints out as 1â€“4 ", do you mean in the pandas dataframe, or in the Excel sheet/csv that you export to? If it is a csv, are you opening it in Excel? I've had similar problems before.

Comment: The weird character shows when I open the csv in Excel. It does not show if I open in a text editor or if I save as .xlsx and open in Excel. But I thought it would be a good idea to standardize.

Comment: In excel, go to the "Data" tab and click "From Text/CSV" in the upper left. When the preview comes up, change the File Origin from "1252: Western European (Windows)" to "65001: Unicode (UTF-8)". Excel does not default to UTF-8.